# How can I see the command string when using MySqlCommand parameters?

Tags: c#, mysql

Having code that looks like:

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(
    "SELECT * FROM DB_name_here WHERE some_field =@some_value;"
);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@some_value", some_string_here);
```

Can I get it back as a simple string for debug purposes, that says:

```
SELECT * FROM DB_name_here WHERE some_field =some_string_here;
```

The obvious cmd.ToString() failed me promptly, returning a   `MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand`.
The cmd.CommandText will return the string with the parameter (`@some_value` in my case).

Any suggestions?

Comment: See this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5356467/from-net-can-i-get-the-full-sql-string-generated-by-a-sqlcommand-object-with-s) Times ago I have used the code and it worked perfectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/265253/939213)  it cannot be done directly.

From the answer:

> At no point in time a complete SQL string is generated.

(For workarounds see the other answers there. especially https://stackoverflow.com/a/265261/939213.)

Comment: Just when you expect something to be simple and straight forward ... meh ... good answer in the links provided. Cheers for that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `CommandText` property of `MySqlCommand` object to get the actual command string .
for parameters you can iterate over `Parameters` and replace with replace the Parameters Parameter `Value`

**Solution:**

```
String commandtext = cmd.CommandText;
foreach (SqlParameter p in cmd.Parameters)
commandtext = commandtext.Replace(p.ParameterName, p.Value.ToString());
```

Comment: :) . You saved me pointing out the bug in your previous version (where you set `commandtext = ""` . Nice catch. This works ok enough, but like the answer that ispiro pointed out, will leave you with strings not quoted. Cheers for the help never the less :)

Comment: @Sudhakar Tillapudi, This does not work in Ubuntu 16.04 with cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@some_value", some_string_here);  Thank you.