# How to get query with parameters form MySqlCommand

Tags: c#, database-connection

I am trying to get the MySQL query text that was generated with the parameters, but so far I have not succeeded.

```
string query = $"UPDATE table_inputs SET amount = @amount WHERE id = @id";
using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection))
{
    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    command.Prepare();

    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", user_id);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@amount", user_amount);
    
    var result = command.ExecuteScalar();   
    // always 'result' equal NULL 
}
```

The request text is required for logging. I plan to write logs from a multi-threaded application where each operation should have its own unique parameters. Consequently, queries with parameters are needed where it was clear what query and with what parameters was performed.
Please tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to do it right.

Comment: use ExecuteNonQuery() and please use Stored procedure

Comment: I use ExecuteNonQuery () in some places, but how do I get the query text with the substituted parameters?

Comment: I don't see any attempt at "*trying to get the MySQL query text ... with parameters*". What have you tried?

Comment: As a result, for this example, I would like to receive a query like: "UPDATE table_inputs SET amount = 100 WHERE id = 45215647"

Comment: @ArchiKu That query doesn't exists in this form, by design. When you use prepared statements the query and the data for it are separated.

Comment: @Progman Tell me how can I make a request with adding parameters in another way? (so that later you can get the correct request body. When adding parameters I use special characters, so i have to do parameters.add (...))

Comment: @Crowcoder I read an article where it was written that the query text should return after executing from ExecuteScalar () and trying to get the text into the variable 'result'. Perhaps this is a mistake, please tell me how to get a request with parameters ?!

Comment: @ArchiKu I don't know what article you have read but the query text is not returned after `ExecuteScalar`. What that does is return the first column of the first row of the first result set. See my answer below, I think it is what you are looking for?

Comment: @ArchiKu Is it an option to use MySQL server side logging as described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303994/log-all-queries-in-mysql/14403905#14403905?

Comment: @Progman Unfortunately no. The server is not mine, they only give me access to several operations with the table.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I see the command string when using MySqlCommand parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20205550/how-can-i-see-the-command-string-when-using-mysqlcommand-parameters)

Comment: Actually there is no replacement of parameters happening. In your case the following is sent to the db server -> 
DECLARE _@amount_ Int
DECLARE _@id_ nvarchar
SET _@amount_ = '435454'
SET _@id_ = 'the_user'
UPDATE table_inputs SET amount = _@amount_ WHERE id = _@id_ ...

Comment: @LegacyCode while one might rightly argue the merits of `AddWithValue`, that code will correctly set parameters, I'm not sure what you are talking about regarding "*there is no replacement of parameters..*"

Comment: @Crowcoder - The point of using parameters is SQL injection prevention. The CommandText itself is not replaced with the values you are passing to SqlParameters. That would kill the point. Instead a DECLARE and SET command is added.

Comment: @Crowcoder the link above uses SqlParameter, with work it looks a little different than with MySqlParameter

Comment: @LegacyCode I know how parameters work. And sql injection is not the only point. I don't understand what you are trying to say. That code is how it is done. The provider takes care of getting the proper command to the database. You don't need to write any DECLARE or SET yourself.

Comment: @ArchiKu it is basically the same. You can use IDbCommand, IDbParameter, etc., if you want to make it more generic.

Comment: @Crowcoder I know... I am just trying to say if you want to "extract" the correct executable command... If... Then you have to do it that way.

Comment: @LegacyCode I understand what you are saying now. I wouldn't expect that to be necessary if you just want to log the queries that occurred. The sql string should be enough to determine what action was taken but that is an assumption on my part.

Comment: @Crowcoder I misunderstand your question in the first place and assumed you want to use the logged sql statements e.g. for checking the result directly in the db.

Comment: @LegacyCode You wouldn't want to run DML statements again. Even for SELECT you have to assume the result set could have changed between when the command was run and when you execute the logged query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not tested and not complete, consider it more psuedo code to give you an idea.

You could write a utility method that takes a command, replaces the parameter placeholders with parameter values, then logs the query.

```
public static void LogCommand(MySqlCommand cmd)
{   
    string cmdText = cmd.CommandText;
    
    foreach(MySqlParameter p in cmd.Parameters)
    {
        cmdText = cmdText.Replace(p.ParameterName, p.Value);
    }

    Log(cmdText); // <-- or however you are logging....
}
```

Comment: This is an interesting solution. Thank you for him! It can also be written in linq and written on one line!

Comment: Same code you can find here https://stackoverflow.com/a/20205594/6527049

Comment: @viveknuna indeed you are right. You can vote to close as duplicate.

Comment: @Crowcoder. no, this is leading to a bad programming practise

Comment: @viveknuna because it is not a stored procedure? I also prefer stored procedures but you cannot make a blanket statement that having SQL in code is bad programming practice.

Comment: @Crowcoder please provide me an example if it benefits?

Comment: @viveknuna Stored procedures require more overhead regarding database maintenance. Using them generally requires a code deployment and a database deployment. That's just one example. Do you also have a problem with ORMs like Entity Framework? You know they generate sql right?

Comment: @Crowcoder But in this case, you cannot deny that we should not use SP

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216426/discussion-between-crowcoder-and-vivek-nuna).

Comment: This will fail with parameters that requires quotes :) .. Like varchar

Comment: @LegacyCode I do not expect the query that is logged to be executed, that was a base assumption on my part. The logged value will show the intent of the query but you are right, if someone is going to try to execute the logged value it will not work unmodified.

Answer (score -1):

Kindly try this below code its working...,

Step 1: Declare the string value.

Step 2: Then Read to the ! Operator method ().

Step 3: After if a condition should be retrieved the data.

```
string val;
string query = $"UPDATE table_inputs SET amount = @amount WHERE id = @id";
using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection))
  {
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
command.Prepare();

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", user_id);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@amount", user_amount);

var result = command.ExecuteNonQuer();
// always 'result' equal NULL 
       
} 
 
 string qur = $"select * from table_inputs where amount = @amount and id = @id";
 using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(qur, connection))
  {
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        command.Prepare();

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", user_id);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@amount", user_amount);

   var result = command.ExecuteReader();  
   if(!result.Read())
   {
       Console.Write("Record not found ");  
   }
   else
   {
        string userid = Convert.ToString(val);  
        userid = dr["@id"].ToString();  
        Console.WriteLine("Your ID is: {@id}", userid.ToString());  
        Console.ReadLine();  
        
        string amt = Convert.ToString(val);  
        amd = dr["@amount"].ToString();  
        Console.WriteLine("Your Amount is: {@amount}", amount.ToString());  
        Console.ReadLine();  
   }
  }
```

Comment: It's code not working.
ExecuteNonQuer() returned int. Int does not contain a definition for read,

Answer (score -1):

Try another option use Store Procedure:

```
 //----SQL Store Procedure----
 CREATE PROCEDURE  Procedurename @Id integer(), @amount number()  
 AS    
 UPDATE table_inputs SET amount = @amount WHERE id = @id   
 go

//-----C# code-----
using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("Procedurename", connection))
{
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", user_id);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@amount", user_amount);
command.ExecuteNonQuer();
}
```

Comment: The question is about logging the sql command, not how to run a sql command.

Comment: I am updating my answer. Kindly refer for your kind information